# toggle current thread flagged state

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I saw a icon indicating "toggle current thread flagged state" when debugger is on.

What's it purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Debug + Windows + Threads.  Note the flag in the first column.  It can sometimes be difficult to find the current thread in this window when your app has a lot of threads.  Especially when the thread doesn't have a good name.  While stepping through code, you can use the "Toggle current thread flagged state" command in the Debug Location command bar to turn on the flag of the current thread.  It also turns on the flag in the Thread combo box on that same command bar.